# How to apply flexbox styling to radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox row with boxes that looks like this.

[image]

And I want to style radio buttons like this, so that they can be checked. 
Is this possible to do?

```
<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.longhand {
  flex-flow: wrap row;
}

.flex-item {
  color: #C3D0D9;
  border: 1px solid #C3D0D9;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: what radio buttons? Do you need to submit form via inputs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep. Hide the input and attach it to a `label` using the `for` attribute, then style the `label`.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
.longhand {
  flex-flow: wrap row;
}
.flex-item {
  color: #C3D0D9;
  border: 1px solid #C3D0D9;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
label {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
input:checked + label {
  background: #eee;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container longhand">
  <li class="flex-item"><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio1">1</label></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio2">2</label></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio3">3</label></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio4">4</label></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio5">5</label></li>
</ul>
```